# How to add homepage URL to SAP business partner?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, bapi, function-module

I'm working on a program witch creates Business Partners in SAP IS-U system. For the creation of business partners I use function module [BAPI_ISUPARTNER_CREATEFROMDATA](http://www.se80.co.uk/sapfms/b/bapi/bapi_isupartner_createfromdata.htm)

I have to add homepage URL too, any idea how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The homepage URL is part of the business partner's communication data, which can either be part of the address data or address-independent communication.

Look at function modules BAPI_BUPA_ADDRESS_ADD/BAPI_BUPA_ADDRESS_CHANGE for updating it with address data (table parameter BAPIADURI) or function modules BAPI_BUPA_CREATE_FROM_DATA/BAPI_BUPA_CENTRAL_CHANGE for address-independent communication, table parameter URIADDRESSDATANONADDRESS.

Unfortunately I do not have access to function BAPI_ISUPARTNER_CREATEFROMDATA to see if it has similar parameters.

Whether or not it must be stored as address-dependent or independent data is a business decision.

As an alternative, you should see whether you can update/create BPs via the BOL.